# I am building a crawler and it loops indefinitely. I want to stop the looping once it has got the data I want to add

Tags: php, web-crawler

I have limited the crawl to a single website. I have also tried to use function linkExists to stop crawling existing links, but the script doesn't stop till it times out. How can I fix that?

I am quite happy to stop the script at a fixed number of loops.

I have been doing a course online on building a search engine and have made a few changes to the original script because I found it to be a little inefficient, yet the main problem still occurs.

There is a problem withing Function linkExists that I am also trying to solve. The original script uses linkExists at the point of inputting to the database and I want to exclude it before crawling.

```
 function LinkExists($url) {
        global $con;
        
        $query = $con->prepare("SELECT url FROM sites WHERE url = :url");
        
        $query->bindParam(":url",$url);
        $query->execute();
        $indata = $query->fetch_Column("url");
            
            }
        return $query->rowCount() != 0;
        }

   

function followLinks($url) {
    
    global $alreadyCrawled;
    global $crawling;
    global $hosta;
    global $indata;
    
    $parser = new DomDocumentParser($url);
    
    $linkList = $parser->getLinks();
    
    foreach($linkList as $link) {
        $href = $link->getAttribute("href");
        
        if((substr($href, 0, 3) !== "../") AND (strpos($href, $hosta) === false)) {
            continue;
        }
        else if(strpos($href, "#") !== false) {
            continue;
        }
        else if(substr($href, 0, 11) == "javascript:") {
            continue;
        }
        
        if(LinkExists($indata) !== "") {
        $alreadyCrawled[] = array_merge($indata, $alreadyCrawled);      
        }
                
        $href = createLink($href, $url);
        
        if(!in_array($href, $alreadyCrawled)) {
            $alreadyCrawled[] = $href;
            $crawling[] = $href;
                        
            getDetails($href);
        }
                    
     }
    array_shift($crawling);
    
    foreach($crawling as $site) {
        followLinks($site);         
     
 }
```